# Create new salt when updating user record

Tags: passwords, salt

When updating a user record (id, username, password, salt), is it wise to also create a new salt for this record or is there no security disadvantage in always using the same salt no matter how often the user changes his password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no (or at best minimal) security advantage to changing the user's salt so long as each user's salt is different and the user is not being specifically targeted.

The point of the salt is 1) to make pre-computing possible hashes harder and 2) to keep it from being apparent that different users are using the same password.  Neither requires that you change the salt.

That said, it certainly doesn't hurt to change the salt as long as you make sure the new salt is unpredictable.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought, but thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the user salt, when the poor user change his username or anything else except the password, you will endup with a wrong hashed-password salt combination.

There is no reason to change the user salt as described from Old Pro but if you want to change it some time do it only when the user change his password.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the salt for other entries than the password? In this case you could not change the salt without rehashing all entries using this salt. There are easier solutions than storing a salt per user though.

Most implementations of hash functions for passwords (for example PHP's [BCrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) implementation), will automatically generate a new secure salt per hash-value, and will return the used salt as part of the hash-value. So there is no need to store the salt separately, and every time you calculate a new hash-value, the function will generate a new salt anyway.

So yes, it is a good thing to create a new salt for every hash calculation, especially because it can be even easier than storing the salt separately.